# Override maximum core limit during free trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am hitting the [maximum of 8 cores](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas) of dataflow using a Free Trial project. See below:

> Note: If you're using a Free Trial project, your project has a maximum of 8 cores available. You must specify a combination of numWorkers, workerMachineType, and maxNumWorkers that fits within your trial limit.

I am willing to pay extra money to use more resources. How can I configure my project to use more than 8 cores when I still have free-trial credit? I cannot find related information in the gcloud documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [$300 free trial FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial), your project can have no more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time. To run more than 8 vCPUs at a time, you must [upgrade your account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#how-to-upgrade).

You can upgrade from the free trial to a paid account through the Google Cloud Platform Console. Click the Upgrade button at the top of the page. If you do not see Upgrade, click the Free trial status icon in the upper-right of the page (resembles a gift-box icon) and Upgrade will appear.

[image: Upgrade GCloud]

You must be a Billing Administrator on the account to make this change. With an upgraded account, you will be automatically charged after your free credits are fully used or after your credits expire, whichever comes first.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did not see the "free trial" or "upgrade" button at all. See my screenshot of gcloud console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw5Aw.png

Comment: What do you see if you go to the billing page? https://console.cloud.google.com/billing

Comment: I see the only billing account, that is linked to "My First Project". This account already contains a payment method. I also can see that the "Free Trial Credit" is visible under this billing account. The user I used is the admin.

Comment: If you see no option to upgrade while moving around different pages of the console, I'd suggest opening a billing ticket. https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Comment: It seems I already upgraded (thus I cannot see the "free trial" button) and the problem is that dataflow jobs launch workers using App Engine API. Both number of CPUs and In-use IP addresses are limited to 8 for each location by default. If you want to increase, you have to explicitly file a request. I will get back to this once it is resolved.